# JSR-250 lifecycle annotations: Annotation Type PreDestroy

Tags: spring, jsr250

Is the method `@PreDestroy` of a prototype bean called when the bean is garbage collected ?

Comment: No it isn't going to be called. With a prototype scoped bean you are responsible for the cleanup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not called when the bean is garbage collected but for the bean to be garbage collected it has to be dereferenced first, which would mean it would have to be destroyed and `@PreDestroy` be called.

So the method won't be called directly but it has to have been called before being garbage collected